# C# MVC 4 Json request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json

I am POSTing a JSON object to a controller action:

```
            $.ajax({
                url: "/path/to/action",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                        name: "John Doe",
                        phone: "2323454543",
                        skills: {
                            code: "php",
                            design: "photoshop"
                            }
                        }
            });
```

How can I map this data to some kind of key-value pair object?  In PHP, these get mapped to an associative array invisibly.  I would like to be able to access properties like this:

```
SomeDynamicType data = ...//something here to prepare json data
string codeSkills = data.skills.code; //codeSkills should = "php"
```

I'm not interested in model binding since these value do not correspond to a model - they are arbitrary.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-to-parse-json-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your .ajax call stringify Json:

```
data: {
                json:
                    JSON.stringify({
                        name: "John Doe",
                        phone: "2323454543",
                        skills: {
                            code: "php",
                            design: "photoshop"
                        }
                    })
            }
```

And accessing properties how you wanted in your controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Action(string json)
        {
            dynamic data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
            string codeSkills = data.skills.code;
...
```

codeSkills is "php" string.

Newtonsoft Json library is available since .NET 4, if I recall correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/), this library parses JSON into a dictionary-like structure. It is used as follows:

```
JObject rss = JObject.Parse(json);
string codeSkills = (string)rss["skills"]["code"];
```